# Correct meaning of 'out of'

Tags: phrase-usage

Vikram (April 12, 2013) posed a question 'Is "work out of" correct English?'. My question is an extension of Vikram's question.
In India where I live, the phrase 'out of' is used with opposite meanings, depending on the context! For example: 
(1) He works out of Delhi - meaning that he works from (that is, based in) Delhi.
(2) She had a child out of wedlock. Here the writer wants to convey that the child was born not from a marriage.

In math, when we say 'She got four out of five answers correct', the phrase 'out of' is used in the sense of 'from' like in example (1) above. 
To avoid confusion, isn't it better to write example (2) above as 'She had a child outside of wedlock?'

Comment: Not quite re: math. In that sense, 'out of' is referring to the division operation and could be replaced by 'divided by'.

Comment: A slight clarification: *out of* is not in general equivalent to *divided by*. *Out of* is more of a subset of *divided by*, which is only used to say *a/b* when *a<=b*.  "Out of" (sometimes shortened to just *of*) in math is a shorter way of saying "from a total number of". So *four out of five questions correct* is saying *four questions from a total of five questions were correct*, which can be (and often is) represented as a fraction: *4/5 questions correct*.

Comment: None of my math teachers ever had a problem with referring to improper fractions like 16/10 as '16 out of 10'.

Comment: It would also be better to write example (1) as *He works from Delhi* or *He is based in Delhi*. Using "out of" in this context, sounds odd and weird.

Comment: Your suggestion for example (2) is not better because it is verbose, wordy. The first wording of example (2) is sufficient.

Comment: @mcalex Interesting, maybe I am stricter than I thought, because I marked people wrong for that when I was teaching.

Comment: @Walter I'm definitely on your side on that one. You can't actually take 16 out of 10, so that doesn't really make sense. "Four out of five" correct is fine, and I agree with your explanation as to why. I don't have any problems with "He works out of Delhi" or "She had a child out of wedlock" either; both sound perfectly natural to me.

Comment: @mcalex Good point.  Perhaps we can explain this difference of opinion by saying there are semantic restrictions: we wouldn't usually say *six out of five answers correct* unless we were trying to be silly, and I think that's because it's nonsense **in that particular context**.  But perhaps answering this question would require more research (on what opinions people hold!).

Comment: "out of wedlock" is idiomatic (partly because nobody says "wedlock" except in this phrase). But I'd guess it's used much less than it used to be, and there are better alternatives ("while unmarried" is IMO best, also "outside of marriage", and there's "illegitimate" although it has its issues.)

Answer (score 1):

American English has both of the same usages you described from Indian English.

> He works out of Delhi

Usually this is used in cases where the worker sometimes travels as part of that work, so he goes out from his home base to work; or when the worker delivers the product of their work to another location.

> Our salesman works out of Delhi but supports clients in Mumbai and Hyderabad.
>
> I know an engineer who works out of Delhi; her designs are manufactured in Shenzhen.

If neither of these situations apply, it would be more usual to say "he works in Delhi", but you might hear "he works out of Delhi" also.

Comment: I agree that *He works out of Delhi* sounds fine in AmE, and I was surprised to read [Tristan's comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9265/correct-meaning-of-out-of#comment15230_9265) that it's unacceptable (presumably in BrE).  I wonder if it's a legitimate difference between AmE and BrE...?

Comment: I think "work out of X" is a bit unusual in UK English, and maybe would be considered business jargon. It would be more usual to say something like "He is based in X" or "His office/home is in X" depending on the precise arrangement.

Comment: I (native AmE speaker) agree that "works out of" sounds fine if the employee/person travels for work. I've also heard it much more frequently in recent years when the employee works for a company based elsewhere. The work could be remote or there might be a satellite office in the location being discussed. (E.g., "Our engineering team works out of the Delhi office and will be traveling to headquarters this spring.")